# Combination of stacked and normal bar graph in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to plot a bar graph in Matlab, where some of the items are normal and some are stacked. How can I achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Y = [5 1 2
     8 3 7
     9 6 8
     5 5 5
     4 2 3];
bar(Y,'stack')
hold on
Ys = sum(Y,2);
stacked = [1 2];    
Ys(stacked) = 0;
bar(Ys,'facecolor','y')
```

[image]